# Spring Boot failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application.xml'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss7.x, ear

When I deploy a Spring Boot application packaged in an ear in Jboss 7.x EAP I get the following error:

```
server.default-host./pepe: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./pepe: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application.xml'
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application.xml'
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:231)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application.xml'
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:476)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:465)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:386)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:225)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:195)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:182)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:168)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:184)
```

The structure of the ear is as follows:

```
├── META-INF
│   ├── application.xml
│   └── jboss-deployment-structure.xml
├── evaluateboot_be-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
└── lib
    ├── asm-5.0.4.jar
    ├── aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar
    ├── bcpkix-jdk15on-1.55.jar
    ├── bcprov-jdk15on-1.55.jar
    ├── bval-core-1.1.2.jar
    ├── cache-api-1.0.0.jar
    ├── ccf2-8.0.0.4_MAPFRE.jar  
    ├── cxf-core-3.1.12.jar
    ├── cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.12.jar
    ├── cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.12.jar
    ├── cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.12.jar
    ├── cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.12.jar
    ├── cxf-rt-security-3.1.12.jar
    ├── cxf-rt-security-saml-3.1.12.jar
    ├── cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.12.jar
    ├── cxf-rt-ws-security-3.1.12.jar
    ├── cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.12.jar
    ├── cxf-spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.12.jar
    ├── cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws-3.1.12.jar
    ├── dom4j-1.6.1.jar
    ├── ehcache-2.10.4.jar
    ├── evaluateboot-bo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ├── evaluateboot_be-commons-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ├── evaluateboot_be-crud-dl-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ├── evaluateboot_be-crud-sr-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ├── evaluateboot_be-crud-sr-impl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ├── evaluateboot_be.zeroConfig-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ├── guava-19.0.jar
    ├── hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final.jar
    ├── httpclient-4.5.3.jar
    ├── httpcore-4.4.8.jar
    ├── jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar
    ├── jackson-core-2.8.10.jar
    ├── jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar
    ├── jasypt-1.9.2.jar
    ├── jaxen-1.1.1_CXF_MAPFRE.jar
    ├── jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar
    ├── jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
    ├── jdom-1.1.jar
    ├── joda-time-2.9.9.jar
    ├── jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
    ├── log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
    ├── logback-classic-1.1.11.jar
    ├── spring-aspects-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar
    ├── spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar
    ├── spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar
    ├── spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar
    ├── spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar
    ├── spring-boot-starter-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar
    ...
```

The version of spring boot that I am using is 1.5.9.

Why is Spring Boot trying to load the ear deployment descriptor, which is in the META-INF folder?

This same ear deploys correctly in Websphere 8.5.5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After carefully reviewing the generated artifacts, I have found that the problem that causes this error is because one of the artifacts has the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId> org.apache.maven.plugins </ groupId>
     <artifactId> maven-jar-plugin </ artifactId>
       <configuration>
          <archive>
             <manifest>
               <addClasspath> true </ addClasspath>
             </ manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
               <Class-Path> ./ META-INF / </ Class-Path>
            </ manifestEntries>
       </ archive>
    </ configuration>
 </ plugin>
```

This is causing it to generate the META-INF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: jose
Class-Path: ./ META-INF/ bval-core-1.1.2.jar gaia-core-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.
jar gaia-commons-devutils-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar gaiafrontend-proxy-2.4.0
-SNAPSHOT.jar gaia-commons-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar MAPFRE_ARQOS_CORE_VIDA.
 ArquitecturaCoreVidaFramework-14.1.12.jar MAPFRE_ARQOS_COMMONS_STANDA
LONE.CommonsExceptions-14.1.12.jar MAPFRE_ARQOS_COMMONS_STANDALONE.En
cryptionServiceProvider-14.1.12.jar MAPFRE_ARQOS_COMMONS_STANDALONE.U
tils-14.1.12.jar MAPFRE_ARQOS_COMMONS_STANDALONE.Log4M-14.1.12.jar MA
PFRE_ARQOS_COMMONS_STANDALONE.CacheServiceProvider-14.1.12.jar MAPFRE
_ARQOS_COMMONS_STANDALONE.Tron21ConnectorErrorExchange-14.1.12.jar do
m4j-1.6.1.jar jaxen-1.1.1_CXF_MAPFRE.jar xercesImpl-2.8.0.jar jdom-1.
1.jar ctgclient-8.0.0.4_MAPFRE.jar ctgserver-8.0.0.4_MAPFRE.jar ccf2-
8.0.0.4_MAPFRE.jar cicseci-8.0.0.4_MAPFRE.jar cicsecitools-8.0.0.4_MA
PFRE.jar cicsframe-8.0.0.4_MAPFRE.jar security-8.0.0.4_MAPFRE.jar spr
ing-aspects-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar commons
-logging-1.2.jar spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar spring-context-sup
port-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar spring-expres
sion-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar spring-oxm-4.3.
13.RELEASE.jar spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE
.jar spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELE
ASE.jar aopalliance-1.0.jar spring-security-ldap-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar sp
ring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE
.jar spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.
jar spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar jackson-core-2.8.10.j
ar jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar cxf-core
-3.1.12.jar woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar stax2-api-3.1.4.jar xmlschema
-core-2.2.2.jar cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.12.jar cxf-rt-databinding-ja
xb-3.1.12.jar cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.12.jar cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws
-3.1.12.jar asm-5.0.4.jar cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.12.jar cxf-rt-ws
-security-3.1.12.jar cxf-rt-security-saml-3.1.12.jar cxf-rt-security-
3.1.12.jar wss4j-policy-2.1.10.jar neethi-3.0.3.jar wss4j-ws-security
-stax-2.1.10.jar wss4j-bindings-2.1.10.jar wss4j-ws-security-policy-s
tax-2.1.10.jar cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.12.jar wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar logback-core-1
.1.11.jar logback-classic-1.1.11.jar slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar commons-io-
2.4.jar commons-codec-1.10.jar commons-pool-1.6.jar commons-lang-2.6.
jar commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar commons-collections-3.2.2.jar commons-bea
nutils-1.9.3.jar validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar cache-api-1.0.0.jar j
oda-time-2.9.9.jar swagger-annotations-1.5.10.jar lombok-1.16.18.jar 
guava-19.0.jar aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar coherence-12.1.2.0.jar ehcach
e-2.10.4.jar wss4j-1.6.7.jar wss4j-ws-security-common-2.0.9.jar xmlse
c-2.0.7.jar jasypt-1.9.2.jar wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.0.9.jar gaiaback
end-core-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar gaia-context-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar spring-jd
bc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar springfox-swagger2-2.6.1.jar swagger-models-1.5
.10.jar springfox-spi-2.6.1.jar springfox-core-2.6.1.jar springfox-sc
hema-2.6.1.jar springfox-swagger-common-2.6.1.jar springfox-spring-we
b-2.6.1.jar classmate-1.3.4.jar spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar 
spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar mapstruct-1.0.0.Final.jar sp
ringfox-swagger-ui-2.6.1.jar gaiabackend-remote-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ga
ia-plinvoker-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar plinvoker-1.0.0-20180208.232239-4.jar
cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws-3.1.12.jar spring-boot-starter-1.5.9.R
ELEASE.jar spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar jul-to-slf4j
-1.7.25.jar log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar snakeyaml-1.17.jar spring-boo
t-starter-web-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.9.RELE
ASE.jar tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar tomcat-annotations-api-8.5.23.ja
r tomcat-embed-el-8.5.23.jar tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar hibern
ate-validator-5.3.6.Final.jar jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar cxf-sprin
g-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.12.jar jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.0
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_20
```

Removing the entry from the plugin:

```
<manifestEntries>
    <Class-Path> ./ META-INF / </ Class-Path>
</ manifestEntries>
```

The *application.xml* file of the ear device is no longer scanned

Answer (score 0):

Actually the application.xml and jboss-deployment-structure.xml file should be present inside the WEB-INF. Could you please check the project structure. If it is a new project, you can use this URL (https://start.spring.io/) to create the project structure. Can you refer the below URL:

https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/ch01s04s02.html

verify the complete structure including the war packaging.

Comment: It is not a new project. It´s a migration of an existing one. The previous version was not based on Spring Boot. The structure of the ear is valid for other JEE servers. In JBoss EAP 7, the file jboss-deployment-structure.xml is placed in WEB-INF when it is a war but in an ear it is usually placed in the META-INF of the ear