# Error deploying Spring boot application in Websphere 8.5.5

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, websphere, ear

I am getting following error message in stdout while starting my application in Websphere  8.5.5:

```
 1/9/20 11:56:48:437 UTC] 000000c0 SystemOut     O 11:56:48.435 [WebContainer : 3] ERROR 
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application.xml'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadForFileExtension(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:494)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:464)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$null$7(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:443)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader$$Lambda$290.0000000000368730.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$8(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:443)
```

The version of spring boot that I am using is 2.2.2.

Why is Spring Boot trying to load the ear deployment descriptor, which is in the META-INF folder?

Comment: Because `XML` is a valid format for properties as well both`.properties` and `.xml` are loaded. Spring uses the default properties support which loads both. Hence it tries to load `application.xml`. I doubt it is in META-INF but rather in the root of your classpath.

Comment: not websphere but try this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955035/spring-boot-failed-to-load-property-source-from-location-classpath-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum)  says, the problem it is giving is because Spring Boot is trying to load the ear artifact's *application.xml* file to get properties and gives a parsing error as it does not have the expected format.

I have had this same error when displaying in application servers and it is solved by taking from the *MANIFEST.MF* file the path /META-INF

In my case, I was including the war plugin with this:

```
<manifestEntries>
   <Class-Path>./ META-INF/</Class-Path>
</manifestEntries>
```

Try deleting that entry and redeploying.